# Laravel get relationship, with distant relationships based on intermediate

Tags: php, laravel

### The Scenario

One order can have multiple order lines. Each order line can have many products. Each product can then have one licence assigned (but only after the order is completed). The licence will be assigned to a single user. To clarify, technically each order line can have one or multiple products, and none, one or many licences for each product on the line.

### Models

- OrderHeader (id, status, currency, ... )
- OrderLine (id, order_header_id, total, ....)
- Product (id, name, parent_id)
- Licence (id, user_id, product_id, order_line_id)
- User (id, name, email, ... )

There is also a order_line_product table, which has order_line_id and product_id fields.

So an order consists of a record from the OrderHeader table, with many records from the OrderLine table, which links to Product via the order_line_product table. The licences are separately added but have the relevant fields to reference a User and OrderLine.

### Requirement

I want to output the date in the following format:

```
OrderHeader
 - OrderLine 1
   - Product 1
     - Licence 1
       - User 1
     - Licence 2
       - User 2
   - Product 2
      - Licence 3
        - User 3
 - OrderLine 2
   - Product 1
 - OrderLine 3
   - Product 1
   - Product 2
     - Licence 4
        - User 4
   - Product 3
```

The key thing is that I want to return one Collection with the relationships loaded properly in this manner.

### Relationship Code In Models

#### OrderHeader

```
public function lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderLine', 'order_header_id', 'id');
}
```

#### OrderLine

```
public function header()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderHeader', 'order_header_id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}

public function licences()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Licence');
}
```

#### Product

```
public function orderLine()
{
    return Product::belongsToMany('App\OrderLine');
}

public function licence()
{
    return Product::belongsToMany('App\Licence');
}
```

#### Licence

```
public function user()
{
    return Licence::belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function line()
{
    return Licence::belongsTo('App\OrderLine', 'order_line_id');
}

public function product()
{
    return Licence::hasOne('App\Product', 'id', 'product_id');
}
```

Hopefully that all flows as expected.

### Current Code

If I use:

```
$order = OrderHeader::findOrFail($id)->load('lines.products', 'lines.licences.user', 'creator');
```

It is very close to the output I want, all the correct data is present, however the 'licence' relationship is not nested within the 'product' relationship. If I output the data, it would be in the following format:

```
OrderHeader
 - OrderLines
   - Products
      - Product 1
      - Product 2
      - etc...
   - Licences
      - Licence 1
        - User
      - Licence 2
        - User
      - etc...
```

I.e. the licences are at the same level of hierarchy as products, not nested within them.

What I want is:

```
OrderHeader
 - OrderLines
   - Products
     - Product 1
       - Licences
         - Licence 1
           - User
```

This will allow me to very easily traverse the full hierarchy of the order, without having to do messy foreach / if checks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following;

```
$order = OrderHeader::findOrFail($id)->load('lines.products', 'lines.products.licence','lines.products.licence.user', 'creator');
```

As you are loading the license from the line not the product itself. Then the addition of the user on top of that should give you the desired structure of the data you want.

Comment: That results in a BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2006:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::license()

Comment: @BigPun Because you named you method in Product model 'licence', so change it to 'license'. / I will update answer.

Comment: Good spot! Changed that, and I get the same error as the previous answer and the code I've attempted myself: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.exp_licence_product' doesn't exist (SQL: select `exp_licences`.*, `exp_licence_product`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `exp_licence_product`.`licence_id` as `pivot_licence_id` from `exp_licences` inner join `exp_licence_product` on `exp_licences`.`id` = `exp_licence_product`.`licence_id` where `exp_licence_product`.`product_id` in (17)) It's assuming a licence_product table exists

Comment: Look into the extra parameters on the belongsToMany relationship method and this should solve that one.

Comment: Fraid not. I've changed the relationship to Product::belongsToMany('App\Licence', 'licences', 'product_id', 'id'); (many licences can have a product_id of the product in question). Gives error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'exp_licences' (SQL: select `exp_licences`.*, `exp_licences`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `exp_licences`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `exp_licences` inner join `exp_licences` on `exp_licences`.`id` = `exp_licences`.`id` where `exp_licences`.`product_id` in (17))

Comment: @BigPun should this not be a hasMany relationship? As it looks like it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68973/discussion-between-bigpun-and-matt-burrow).

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the licence on the user when you said you wanted it on the products.  Try this instead.

```
$order = OrderHeader::findOrFail($id)->load('lines.products.licence.user');
```

I've also got a feeling your relationships are incorrectly using `belongsToMany()` as I don't see any pivot tables, but without seeing your schema, I can't be sure.  From what you have, it looks like all you should be using is `belongsTo()` and `hasOne()` or `hasMany()`.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the core fields to define the schema. The pivot table is just order_line_product, which joins multiple products to multiple lines. I tried using your code but I get the error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.exp_licence_product' doesn't exist. Looks like it's trying to join licence to product through a pivot table instead of reading the values from the licence